# RubyMine has detected that some of the gems are not installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

I am using rvm to manage my gemsets. I have one specific gemset called ruby-2.1.2@internal_management_system, and from the terminal in mac osx I am able to get my rails app running. However, when I try to get the same app running in RubyMine, I get the following message:

```
RubyMine has detected that some of the gems required for 'internal_management_system' are not installed
```

Then in RubyMine when i try to run the project, I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /Users/myuser/projects/internal_management_system/test/dummy/bin/rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -e development
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize': Could not find rake-10.4.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
```

It doesn't seem to be using the right gemset at all. When I run rvm gemdir from terminal, I get this:

```
/Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@internal_management_system
```

I believe I followed all the prerequisites. I did the following:

- created the gemset within the console
- made sure the ruby interpreter and gemset was installed in the default rvm folder ~/.rvm
- created a .ruby-gemset, which contains internal_management_system, and .ruby-version, which contains 2.1.2.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I did find one solution. When I went to Run | Edit Configurations, and under Ruby SDK, I switched from

```
Use project SDK: internal_management_system
```

to

```
Use other SDK: RVM: ruby-2.1.2 [internal_management_system].
```